# ksoap2 android incompatible xml

Tags: android, xml, jax-ws, android-ksoap2

I have a problem connecting to a jax-ws web service from Android (using ksoap2).

I have tried looking for similar problems and I have found a lot of them, but none of their solutions seem to be working for me.

My webmethod `login` takes two Strings and outputs another String containing the result. (To avoid any datatype/incompatability/speed issues, we decided to only use Strings with the web service)

**What my jax-ws is expecting:** (according to my ?Tester page)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:login xmlns:ns2="http://jrpg.easj/">
            <username>foobar</username>
            <password>pswd2</password>
        </ns2:login>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

**What ksoap2 spits out:** (httpTransport.requestDump)

```
<v:Envelope 
    xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <n0:login xmlns:n0="http://jrpg.easj/">
            <n0:username i:type="d:string">foobar</n0:username>
            <n0:password i:type="d:string">pswd2</n0:password>
        </n0:login>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

In the response I can see that it is always unsuccessful, even with a correct login. So the web service must not recognize the username and password... So I have to assume that this is due to the xml format. Or possibly a problem with the character encoding, but I am leaning more towards it being an xml format issue.

**Is there any way of changing the format?**
and, btw... does anybody know what the v: is for?
I am guessing the S: is for soap or something, but... well I don't even know if any of them are significant...

I have just followed a toturial, so there is a lot of code, and some of it I haven't completely grokked yet... and I'm not sure if there is any specific part that would be handy, for answering this question... so I will just keep it short and leave out the java code. But, let me know if there is a specific piece of the code you need to see.

I have connected other applications (.net/vs, java/netbeans) to the same web service. And the process is always so painless and simple that anyone can do it... So it frustrates me that Android has to be so backwards and difficult about it. So of cause, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I may be on to the solution now. The tutorial said to use this code when adding parameters.

```
PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
property.setNamespace(WS_NAMESPACE);
property.setName("username");
property.setValue(username);
request.addProperty(property);
```

...but without the namespace line, the "n0:" in front of the parameters will disappear, and I can now get the expected results from the web method.

```
PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
//property.setNamespace(WS_NAMESPACE);
property.setName("username");
property.setValue(username);
request.addProperty(property);
```

The ksoap connection still throws a lot of errors, but now at least I can get the proper results from the web methods. So that's a start.